# Bug? Não consigo somar o parâmetro no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Bom dia.

Então, sobre a pergunta, eu estou tentando refatorar meu código para OO e tenho o seguinte problema:

*(esse é um código mínimo do problema que reproduz o problema)*

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Um título legal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn-click">Click</button>
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.js

```
class Test {
  add(level) {
    level += 1;
  }
}

export default new Test();
```

main.js

```
import Test from "./Test.js";
let level = 1;


document.getElementById("btn-click").addEventListener("click", () => {
    Test.add(level);
    console.log(level);
});
```

Alguém saberia uma possível solução?

**EDIT1:** Era para somar o level em 1 ao chamar o Test.add(level), porém não é isso que acontece.

Comment: Onde e exatamente qual o seu erro?

Comment: Cara abre as ferramentas de desenvolvedor do Chrome e vê se está dando algum erro de CQRS acho que o seu script `main.js` não está sendo carregado.

Answer (score 0):

Solução:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Um título legal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn-click">Click</button>
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.js

```
class Test {
  add(levelObject) {
    levelObject.level += 1;
  }
}
export default new Test();
```

main.js

```
import Test from "./Test.js";
let levelObject = {
    level: 1,
};

document.getElementById("btn-click").addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(levelObject.level);
    Test.add(levelObject);
});
```